# Is it possible to create relationships between tables?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, bigdata

Bigquery seems great, I have a database type ETL, where my scheme has several relationships between entities, I would like to know if there is a way to make relations between them, or if they can be simulated in some way between the datasets?

Forgive my English, it's not my language and I do not know it very well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't explicitly create relationship in BigQuery. Big Query philosophy is to denormalize the data to have better performance on querying. When they need relation, BigQuery use repeated fields (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/legacy-nested-repeated)

But if performance don't matter and you want to have relationship, you can normalize your data and manually make JOIN (or nested SELECT) on some fields when you are querying your data.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Comment: I was just reading something like that, and I apologize for asking another question, but is not there a structure similar to NoSql in bigquery, or indeed, bigquerye is a NoSql database?

Comment: BigQuery is a SQL (supports SQL syntax) although it’s often encouraged (depending on the use case) when designing schema and loading data to BigQuery to denormalize it (for better performance) which one of the characteristics of NoSQL databases.

so, in essence, BigQuery is SQL but you can use some NoSQL practices as well.

> answer from https://www.quora.com/Is-BigQuery-a-SQL-or-NoSQL