# Google Professional Cloud Architect Exam - BigQuery vs Cloud Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Recently I cleared the google cloud PCA exam but want to clarify one question which I have doubt.

" You are tasked with building online analytical processing (OLAP) marketing analytics and reporting tools. This requires a relational database that can operate on hundreds of terabytes of data. What is the Google-recommended tool for such applications?"

What is the answer? Is it Bigquery or cloud spanner? as there are 2 parts in question. If we consider it for OLAP then it is Bigquery and for 2nd part for RDBMS it should be Cloud Spanner.

Appreciate it if I can have some clarification.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Online Analytical Processing (OLAP) databases, consider using BigQuery.

When performing OLAP operations on normalized tables, multiple tables have to be JOINed to perform the required aggregations. JOINs are possible with BigQuery and sometimes recommended on small tables.

You can check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse#advantages_of_denormalization) for further information.

BigQuery for OLAP and Google Cloud Spanner for OLTP.

Please check [this other page](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-oracle-to-cloud-spanner) for more information about it.

Comment: Appreciated both of your response but still the 2nd part of the question i.e relational database which Bigquery can't fulfil since it is not a RDBMS. Tried to contact Google for explanation but they too failed to give clear response.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the question is confusing.

But according to the official documentation :

[Other storage and database options](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview)

> If you need interactive querying in an online analytical processing
> (OLAP) system, consider BigQuery.

However BigQuery is not considered relational database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The big query does not provide you relationship between tables but you can join them freely.
If your performance falls cluster then partition on the joining fields.

[Is it possible to create relationships between tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267761/is-it-possible-to-create-relationships-between-tables)

Some more literature if some want to go into the details.

> By using MapReduce, enterprises can cost-effectively apply parallel
> data processing on their Big Data in a highly scalable manner, without
> bearing the burden of designing a large distributed computing cluster
> from scratch or purchasing expensive high-end relational database
> solutions or appliances.

https://cloud.google.com/files/BigQueryTechnicalWP.pdf

Hence Bigquery